# Hide Taskbar for Single Monitor

Tags: windows, windows-10, window-manager, multi-monitor

I have a strange monitor setup with 6 monitors, two of them are on top of the other 4, and I would like to hide the taskbar on the two monitors on top. Sadly, hiding the taskbar doesn't change the desktop working area, so maximized windows won't fill up the screen completely.
I am only searching for a way to hide these taskbars, not a replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive if this will meet your requirements, but RealTimeSoft has a program called [Ultramon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon) that has a lot of [taskbar features](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/smart_taskbar.asp).  It's more of an add-on than a replacement.  I've never used it for the purpose you are trying to achieve though.  It has a free 30-day trial, so you've got nothing to lose at least.